# Pointer validity in a loop construct?

Tags: c, pointers

Well, I have searched all over and couldn't find anything, so please excuse if this question was already asked.

In C (gcc, Linux x86_64), trying to test a pointer using this code works:

```
if(ptr) { ... }
```

But I get a segfault when I do this:

```
while(set1) {
    n++;
    set3 = realloc(set3, sizeof(int) * n);
    set3[n-1] = *set1;
}
```

or even this:

```
  for(; set1; set1++) {
    n++;
    set3 = realloc(set3, sizeof(int) * n);
    set3[n-1] = *set1;
    set1++;
  }
```

Can someone explain me this? Where am I going wrong? :S

NB: The code inside `if' said above was just for testing, I don't need it actually

Comment: can you share rest of the loop?

Comment: Show us what's in the body of the statement.

Comment: The problem is in your `...` part, obviously. Can you show it?

Comment: Aren't you by any chance goint in an infinite loop with `while` and `for`?

Comment: Question updated, check the code :)

Comment: btw, there's no segmentation fault on C (gcc, Linux x86).

Comment: Terrible code. How do the loops go to an end?

Comment: @Stan, set1 is a limited dynamic array created using realloc() in main(), the loop terminates when the pointer becomes invalid.

Comment: See Kerrek's answer, when the ptr becomes invalid, the loop will NOT terminates, that's the point :)

Comment: @Nilesh: yes, because I was using only printf() to test. I wasnt accessing illegal memory.

Comment: FWIW, if you don't change ptr1, and it is not NULL, the first loop will go on and on and one time, you will reach a point where no more memory can be allocated. If you access ptr3 after that, it will be invalid too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what "testing a pointer" means. The condition `if(p)` is identical to `if(p != 0)`, so *all* you are testing is whether the pointer is null or not. There is **nothing** that tells you whether it's OK to dereference any given pointer.

In particular, `for(; ptr; ptr++) { ... }` will just continue incrementing the pointer forever; if you dereference `ptr` in the body, you will almost certainly cause an access violation eventually.

**You are responsible yourself for knowing by how much you can increment the pointer!**

(Silly aside: If you are not dereferencing `ptr` at all, this might loop around until `ptr` overflows and is 0 again, but this may never happen depending on the initial value of `ptr` and on `sizeof(*ptr)`.)

Comment: Okay so it means I need to keep a counter variable and cannot do something like, "when the pointer becomes invalid, break out of the loop"?

Comment: Right. That counter is usually called "array size" or something mnemonic like that. There is no built-in notion of "checking whether a pointer points to something valid". It simply cannot be done (in any reasonable way). E.g.: `for (T * q = p; q < p + N; ++q) { ... *q ... }`, or `while(N--) { ... *p++ ... }` etc.

Comment: `if(p)` is equivalent to `if(p != 0)`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

i'd guess ptr is not null (so the if will evaluate to true) but your pointer is not valid (i.e: it was freed, or even if ptr=1 the "if" will evaluate to true but you wont be able to access the memory position 1)

maybe you can try fprintf(stdout, "%p", ptr) in different parts of your code so you can trace where the value was messed up, we really need more details here :)

Comment: Pointer is perfectly valid, because I can deference it and print the value present! Moreover, I tried ptr != NULL in for & while, doesn't work either. Segfaults.

Comment: A pointer can contain any bit combination that fit in its size. The only valid pointers are however those that contain the address of a live object or allocated memory. But any other random combination can, by accident, point at memory that is accessible by your app, but is not a valid object or piece of memory. Then you will be able to print a value, but what it is is undefined. IOW, the fact you can derefence and print a value does not mean your pointer is valid. There is no sure way to tell if a pointer is valid. You can only say that nil or NULL are certainly invalid.

Comment: One example: You malloc() a piece of memory and keep a pointer to it. Say it contains a few integers. You access these integers and print their values. So far so good, since the pointer is valid. But if you freemem() the memory, you can still dereference the pointer you have, and if the memory was not re-used yet, you may even be able to retrieve a value you put there. But the pointer is invalid, since it points to freed memory. There is no way to distinguish valid from invalid pointers just from their value. Only proper programming logic can ensure that you don't have invalid pointers.